# System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied when using MessagePack

Tags: c#, messagepack

I'm trying to use MessagePack to serialize my objects, but whenever I try to run the serialization I'm getting an Unhandled Exception error.

Here's my code:

CSCDP_TCPClient.cs

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using MsgPack;
using MsgPack.Serialization;

namespace CSCDPApp
{
    class CSCDP_TCPClient
    {
        public void Connect(string server, int portno, Script Script)  
        {

            var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<Script>();
            var tempstream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Pack(tempstream, script);

            tempstream.Position = 0;

            var deserializedObject = serializer.Unpack(tempstream);
            Debug.WriteLine("Same object? {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(script, deserializedObject));
        }
    }
}
```

Script.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSCDPApp
{
    class Script
    {
        public string cardID;
        public string time;
        public string device;
        public string command;

        public Script()
        {
            //Parameterless Constructor for serialization
        }

        public Script(string cardID, string time, string device, string command)
        {
            this.cardID = cardID;
            this.time = time;
            this.device = device;
            this.command = command;
        } 
    }
}
```

And I'm just calling it in main with:

```
        CSCDP_TCPClient tcpclient = new CSCDP_TCPClient();
        Script tempscript = new Script("test1","test2","test3","test4");
        tcpclient.Connect("0.0.0.0",1,tempscript);
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied: 'MsgPack.Serial
ization.MessagePackSerializer`1[CSCDPApp.Script]'.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, I
nt32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.FieldBasedSerializerEmitter.Crea
teConstructor[T]()
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializerEmitter.CreateInstance
[T](SerializationContext context)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.ILEmittingSerializerBuilder`2.<>
c__DisplayClass5a.<CreateSerializerConstructor>b__59(SerializationContext contex
t)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AbstractSerializers.SerializerBuilder`3.BuildSeriali
zerInstance(SerializationContext context)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AutoMessagePackSerializer`1..ctor(SerializationConte
xt context, ISerializerBuilder`1 builder)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.MessagePackSerializer.CreateInternal[T](Serializatio
nContext context)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.SerializationContext.GetSerializer[T](Object provide
rParameter)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.MessagePackSerializer.Get[T](SerializationContext co
ntext, Object providerParameter)
   at CSCDPApp.CSCDP_TCPClient.Connect(String server, Int32 portno, Script scrip
t) in d:\TFS\MSVC 2013_CTSDev1\CommonComponents\sdnet\tools\CSCDPService\CSCDPAp
p\CSCDP_TCPClient.cs:line 21
   at CSCDPApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\TFS\MSVC 2013_CTSDev1\CommonCom
ponents\sdnet\tools\CSCDPService\CSCDPApp\Program.cs:line 64
```

I have my visual studio project in my D: drive, and I've checked that permissions are correct. I have the MessagePack.dll in the same directory as all my compiled executeables and have the reference linked. Is there anything I might possibly be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! My Script class wasn't declared public which is why the serializer couldn't find it